# Compile the same Delphi component package but different versions in the same ide

Tags: delphi

Im currently using AlphaControls pack version 12 & Would like to add AlphaControls Pack version 14 to the same ide without removing my old version of AlphaControls.

I have attempted to install the new AlphaControls pack yet have an error on runtime & could not find any source to fix this issue.

The goal is to use AlphaControls pack version 12 & AlphaControls pack version 14 in the same ide, so i do not have to redesign my older projects with the new AlphaControls version.

Comment: Yeah, tough, the system isn't designed for that. You have to uninstall one set of packages, and then install the others.

Comment: I see thanks for the help.

Comment: What you're trying to do is technically impossible from within the same IDE environment. You cannot have more than 1 of the same component name registered in the same environment. What you *could* do is set up a different environment under the same IDE - if I recall, it's using a command line switch such as /r for registry, where you give it a unique name and it uses a separate registry key and config altogether. But the same project will not be able to make use of both concurrently.

Comment: Check this, specifically the `r` option: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options

Comment: [Delphi Settings Manager](https://github.com/Arvur/DelphiSettingManager) to the rescue? It hasn't been updated for 4 years though.

Comment: @PeterWolf I would find it very hard to trust that, especially since it starts off mentioning "C# Builder" (as well as many other places). Surely they mean "C++ Builder". It also goes on to explain a possible bug of destroying your settings... And the "documentation" says last updated in 2005...

Comment: @Jerry C# Builder was a thing. A total flop FWIW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Interesting, first time hearing about it. I do know about the attempt at .NET though. Either way, the overall project looks to be not only outdated, but thrown together.  I'd have more faith in just using the `r` command line option to run in a separate environment.

Comment: To expand on @DavidHeffernan's rather terse comment, the IDE will not allow you to install two packages that contain components with the same name. You'll have to choose one or the other. Most components are designed with backward compatibility in mind (at least the ones I've used), so just changing to use the new version shouldn't cause major issues. If they do, then Jerry's suggestion about using two different IDE configurations while doing the migration to the new version is probably your best bet.

Comment: @KenWhite AlphaControls 14 are not fully backward compatible with older versions.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That's a shame. Someone should let the vendor/author know about the problems that causes. In the meantime, I guess the OP will have to either bite the bullet and do the updates required to make the switch or use two different IDE configurations to allow them to co-exist.

Comment: @KenWhite Author know about this as it is stated in version 14 changeloog. I'm guessing there were some larger internal changes made in version 14 which unfortunately made in incompatible with older versions.